# Error: "has no parameters and arguments were supplied" C# con SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola Buenas Tardes ...

TEngo un problema con el siguiente código en base a un Stored Procedure en SQL Server ...

**Descripción del Problema**
Estoy realizando un proyecto para una papelería con C# y Sql Server como motor de base de datos. 
Me estan funcionando correctamente los SP que declaré y no hay ningún error, pero, al momento de que cargue el DataGridView después de la Acción Insertar, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error en la consola

> Error: Procedure sp_VerCategorias has no parameters and arguments were
>   supplied.

Pero, viendo mi código, no estoy mandando ningún parámetro a la CapaDatos o CapaNegocio ... La función no recibe nada, funciona con el método load, pero, para recargar el gridview, me salta el mensaje mencionado.

Adjunto Código

**CapaDatos**

```
public DataTable MostrarC()
{
   DataTable dtCategorias = new DataTable();

   try
   {
       sqlCommand.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();

       sqlCommand.CommandText = "sp_VerCategorias";
       sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

       SqlDat.Fill(dtCategorias);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dtCategorias = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    return dtCategorias;
}
```

**CapaNegocio**

```
public class N_Categoria
    {
        private D_Categoria _Categoria = new D_Categoria();

        public DataTable MostrarC()
        {
            return _Categoria.MostrarC();
        }

        public string Insertar(string nombre, string descripcion)
        {
            _Categoria.Nombre = nombre;
            _Categoria.Descripcion = descripcion;
            return _Categoria.Insertar(_Categoria);
        }
    }
```

**CapaPresentacion**

```
public partial class Frm_Categorias : Form
    {

        private N_Categoria _Categoria = new N_Categoria();
        private int Id;

        private void MsgError(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void MsgOK(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "Acción Realizada", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void LimpiarCampos()
        {
            this.txtNombre.Text = "";
            this.txtDescripción.Text = "";
            this.txtCodigo.Text = "";
            this.txtNombre.Focus();
        }

        private void MostrarC()
        {
            grData.DataSource = _Categoria.MostrarC();
        }

        public Frm_Categorias()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Frm_Categorias_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MostrarC();
        }

        private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rpta = "";

            rpta = _Categoria.Insertar(this.txtNombre.Text, this.txtDescripción.Text);

            if (rpta.Equals("OK"))
                MsgOK("Categoría Registrada");
            else
                MsgError("Error al registrar la categoría");

            this.MostrarC();
            this.LimpiarCampos();
        }
    }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_VerCategorias]
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Tbl_Categoria;
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda ...

Answer (score 0):

Deberias definir la variables de forma local al metodo y no global, ya que esto puede asignar parametros desde otra instancia que no veo este quitando

Algo como esto

```
public DataTable MostrarC()
{
   DataTable dtCategorias = new DataTable();

   try
   {
        var conn = conexion.AbrirConexion();

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqCommand("sp_VerCategorias", conn)
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

        SqlDat.Fill(dtCategorias);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dtCategorias = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return dtCategorias;
}
```